# Visual Studio SSRS parameters

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

Currently working on a report 
i would show you the images explaining what im trying to do but i keep getting spam downvoted 
Anyway 
when i select my startdate
i want my report to automatically select the enddate so i can hide it

Firstdayofweek = @startdate
Lastdayofweek = @enddate

Script for enddate in my data set it

```
select distinct
CAST(lastdayofweek AS DATE) as LastDayOfWeek 
FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[Calendar] 
WHERE datetime <= DATEADD("DAY",-7,GETDATE())
and dateadd(DAY,6,Firstdayofweek) =LastDayOfWeek 
and FirstDayOfWeek in (@FirstDayOfWeek)
order by 1 desc
```

so when i select say 07/09/2015 then the report will refresh with the enddates,

im at this point 
i now want the user to ONLY select the first date and the endate will automatically select the endates that relate to the startdates

Things to know, Report is a matrix, so startdate can be multiple dates, the report needs to select all of them

and what setting is it for me to change the parameter to hidden and have it auto select the dates

Comment: To hide the parameter simply go to the Report Parameters window and click the "hidden" checkbox

Comment: It looks like you don't need LastDayOfWeek (or enddate) parameter in your report at all, You can just handle it using one parameter.